# django-cms: link to plugin with hashtag

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a "contact" link on a webpage, that needs a #idxx hashtag added, so the browsers directly shows contact infos (that is on a about page). As the link is quite static, I've added it with django-cms's `{% page_url 'contact' %}` tag, and then manually added the hash. BUT: As soon as I change something on the contacts page, and then publish the changes, the plugin's id will change. I already enhance the menu with selected plugins (Institute / About / Contact) Is there an elegant solution for this problem, for example accessing the menu again, only for that specific node?

Real world example: http://www.wti.org

**EDIT:** I if possible, an solution that is 'invisible' for the user/editor, is preferred. Means: No parent plugins to put things in, no manual ids that users have to set. If possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple solution be to assign the target a static id, e.g. `#contactinfo`? Many plugins allow to give them a static id. If your target plugin does not, you could have it preceded by an empty Style plugin. I use aldryn-style, available here: https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-style

Comment: thx, yes, that would be the solution. I prefer a "invisible" solution (for the user/editor), but if there isn't any, I'll gladly accept your answer...give me some more days ;-)

Comment: Hm. I do not know how "invisible" you can get. Somehow you'll have to tell the browser the id you want to jump to. The plugin's id will keep changing and I assume will actually become literally "invisible" if you look at the published page. Or am I missing something?

Comment: the plugin's id doesnt get invisible, just hard to get, as it seems to change at every publish. this works, currently: http://wti.org/institute/about/#18345-contact-and-location

Comment: I'll probably just stick with slugifying the title of the item...not unique, but not supposed to break easily.